# How to process html editor whole content of a single post

Tags: html-editor, customization

Given that I'm new about WordPress, I was not able to find any plugin implementing search & replace functionality for the html editor of a single post. Is there any technical difficulty in processing (through code) the content (changing underlying database, as if content was changed manually) of html editor?

Actually I'd like to have in the html editor a button for regex search & replace (limited to a single post) and also a button for XQuery or other DOM processing (adding an xml header and disguising `&nbsp;` as some valid xml entity was enough to make my posts valid xml).

Thanks in advance for your attention, and sorry if I got something wrong.

Comment: 1) I'd check the [TinyMCE plugins](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/) for any functionality you feel is missing. 2) You could add advanced features/plugins through with help from [this documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons). Maybe those will help, I can't provide you with an "answer" per se but this should guide you.